# How to delete a file from a C++ app without console window in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io

I need to delete a temporary file from my C++ windows application (developed in Borland C++ Builder). Currently I use a simple:

```
system("del tempfile.tmp");
```

This causes a console window to flash in front of my app and it doesn't look very professional. How do I do this without the console window?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you need the Win32 function [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915(VS.85).aspx)().  You will need to `#include <windows.h>` to use it.

Comment: Since the standard remove() function performs the same task and is a part of the standard, I would vote for it rather than the windows function.

Comment: Fair enough.  I think it depends on the style of the rest of the code.  If you're using Win32 functions in other places anyway then it's clearer to stick with DeleteFile().  Since the original question included very Windows-specific system calls I suggested DeleteFile() as a more Windows-y solution.

Answer (score 16):

Or, even the standard C library function `int remove( const char *path );`.

Answer (score 2):

For a slightly more portable (I.e. that works in both Windows and UNIX), I use unlink() or the ISO conformant _unlink() in io.h  (unlink() for UNIX include unistd.h)
Remove() actually calls _unlink().